# Decrypt Image encrypted with PGP

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, pgp

I have an image of an HD which is probably encrypted with PGP with the AES algorithm (256 Bit), I'm not 100% sure though. The image itself is self decrypting and contains a bootloader at the beginning (offset 0) which is not encrypted and a windows system. I don't know how many partitions the image has. I could extract 5 PGP Master Volume AES 256-Bit keys of a memory dump saved of a suspended VM, I've dumped the memory twice after a reboot to verify it's not just randomly detecting memory junk as keys. So now I need to determine where the encrypted partition or partitions begins, because the image has no NTFS header.

I would really appreciate it if somebody can help me with the decryption of the image, I'm even willing to pay.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.